# what is the difference between windows.storage.streams and system.io.stream?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, stream

what is the difference between windows.storage.streams and system.io.stream? When should we use windows.storage.streams over system.io.stream in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [windows.storage.streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams?view=winrt-22621) is a namespace and [system.io.stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-6.0) is a class.

The `system.io.stream` belongs to .Net and you could use it anywhere that uses .Net. You could use it in UWP apps as well but most of the UWP APIs require a special steam class as the parameter like `FileInputStream`. So you have to convert the `system.io.stream` object to `IRandomAccessStream`.

The `windows.storage.streams` namespace contains many steam classes that work for different scenarios like `FileInputStream`. These streams are designed for Windows Runtime. So when you are developing a UWP app, you should use the steams from the `windows.storage.streams` namespace.